# discontinuous functions on open set $O$ and closed set $K$

Tags: real-analysis

Given an open set $O$ and a closed set $K$ in $\Bbb R$, I need to construct two functions $f, g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ where $f$ is discontinuous only on $K$ and $g$ discontinuous only on $O$. They both need to be continuous elsewhere.

Can I define both $f$ and $g$ to be the Dirichlet functions on $K$ and $O$ respectively while they are constant (of value $2$) elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of $K$ (the closed subset) yes, your choice of $f$ works. Indeed, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus K$ (since $K$ is closed), and it is discontinuous on $K$ - **Hint**: pick $x_0\in K$ and prove that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\neq f(x_0)$. It may help to distinguish the cases $x_0\in \operatorname{Int} K$ and $x_0\in \partial K$.

On the other hand, for $O$ your choice of $g$ does not work (unless $O=\mathbb{R}$), because $g$ is discontinuous in $\overline{O}$ and not just on $O$. Indeed, if $x_0\in \partial O$ then $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\neq f(x_0)=2$.

**Hint**: To obtain a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the required conditions, start by constructing a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is discontinuous on an open interval $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$, $-\infty\leq a<b\leq +\infty$, but continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus (a,b)$. Then use the fact that any open subset $O\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a (countable) union of disjoint open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$.

**Hint 2:**

> To construct a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is discontinuous only on $(a,b)$, start by defining $g=0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus (a,b)$. Now you just need to complete the definition by defining $g$ on $(a,b)$ so that $g$ is discontinuous on $(a,b)$ but $\lim_{x\to a^+}g(x)=\lim_{x\to b^-}g(x)=0$. Can you modify the Dirichlet function on $(a,b)$ in a way to make this hold?

Comment: looks like I need to make parabola passing through $(a, 0)$ and $(b, 0)$ on $(a, b)$.

Comment: You mean a parabola multiplied by the Dirichlet function? Then yes that would work. Or just a "triangle"-shaped linear function.

Comment: it's best to use distance function from $O$ to $O^c$ multiplied by Dirichlet function since it generalizes all intervals.